# Is cache memory unnecessary in microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, memory, cache

Do we use cache memory in microcontrollers, if not, why not? If yes, what is its application in embedded systems or it is enough just to have RAM?

Comment: The Freescale (NXP) Vybrid I'm currently working with does have cache (L1 + optional L2).

Comment: It's unnecessary in all processors (time constraints aside) It's a speed optimisation rather than essential equipment.

Comment: I don't think anybody builds PCs (or smartphones) these days without some form of cache onboard. Doesnt that make it necessary to some extent? Not unlike using RAM to limit hard disk accesses, and thus boost the speed of running programs?

Comment: I agree with @BrianDrummond. Cache only delivers a benefit when the microcontroller runs faster than memory. If memory can keep up, then cache increases complexity for no value. There has been a growing performance gap between memory and CPU for many years at the 'top end' of systems. However that doesn't mean the majority of MCUs are even near the 'top end' of systems. Could you explain *exactly* what you mean by *microcontroller* and *cache*? Is reading more than one instruction in a single read, because flash memory is much wider than one instruction, a cache, or a buffer?

Comment: NXP Vybrid VF5xxR comes with two cores - 400MHz Cortex-A5 and 167Mhz Cortex-M4. It is somewhat different from common microcontrollers :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cache memory adds a level of latency unpredictability that may be unwanted. A lot (most?) of microcontrollers are used in a realtime setting where you have to budget for worst-case timing. It does not matter if your code is fast *on average*, if there is a chance that it won't meet the deadline in *worst case*. Worst case would be that your code or data is not in the cache, and since you have to budget for it anyway, the cache just adds extra cost and complexity.

Some microcontrollers I have worked with has a small embedded SRAM that can be used as a "manual cache". You put stuff there that must have a low latency, be it code or data.

Now, the term "microcontroller" is becoming more and more bloated. Is the 8-core ARM processor in your phone a microcontroller? If so, then yes, of course it should have a cache.

Comment: the cortex-m4 falls into this category of is it a microcontroller?  from the embedded flash and ram and how it executes yes, but it has caches and an fpu and can be clocked pretty fast, from those no it is not a microcontroller.

Comment: Most µC that run >25 MHz have a cache for flash memory. Flash memory is a bit slow even when reading.

Answer (score 3):

Above a certain speed, fast memory costs more per byte than slow memory (below that speed, making memory slower won't make it any cheaper).  If a system has a large amount of memory, having most of it be slow but then including a cache of fast memory and the logic to run it will be cheaper than making all of the memory fast.  If the system doesn't run very fast, however, memory which can keep up with the system won't cost more than slower memory, so there's no reason not to have all the memory be fast enough to keep up with the system.  If the system is fast but doesn't have much memory, the cost savings from making the bulk of the memory slow won't be sufficient to justify the cost of adding a cache.

Many microcontrollers have a flash interface which can fetch multiple bytes at once into a buffer; while this might be viewed as a sort of cache, in many cases it won't be an addressable memory, since each bit of the buffer will only be able to take data from a single source [a bit line from the flash array].

Answer (score 1):

Having a level 1 cache is a trade-off between speed and cost. For speed, the bigger you make memory, the the longer the path to the data gets. That means that it'll take longer and longer (in terms of latency) the more memory you add. At some point performance degrades due this latency, which is the point when adding a level 1 cache makes sense. Cost is also a consideration, in that high-speed memory is more expensive than other types of memory. Finally, an additional benefit is that caches can make the micro-controller oblivious to the *kind* of memory it is read from.

Micro-controllers have typically had small memories, and therefore they often have no level 1 cache. In a sense their whole memory could be considered a level 1 cache! However, many micro-controllers today are very capable and start crossing over into the micro-processor territory, with bigger memories and therefore also level-1 (and level-2) caches.

Having caches adds a rather significant toll on the programming side, since real-time behavior on cache-misses can be hard to predict. Sometimes, this doesn't matter and/or can be worked around, but in the cases where it does there are a few options:

- Use smaller micro controllers for specific sub-tasks in a larger system.
- Use a chip that has embedded physical real-time units.

The first solution is quite attractive, as micro-controllers are cheap and capable. However, communication between the controllers and the main (CPU) unit could become an issue. This is why chips with embedded real-time capabilities can be a better solution.

As with all engineering, there are pros and cons for every solution. Pick the right tool for the job!

Comment: The register bank is nothing like a cache, especially not in a micro controller. Just because it's fast does not imply that something is a cache.

Comment: @pipe Thanks, I must have gotten that wrong (or else naming changed over time). It seems level 0 cache is used now for the micro-instruction cache. I've edited that part.